# Анимация появления страницы

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, анимация, frontend

подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно реализовать такую первую анимацию отображения страницы - https://ramzes.gg/

Что можно почитать или найти, чтобы реализовать похожее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализаций может быть несколько, кто-то делает svg-mask-animation в связке с js, в вашем же примере гораздо проще, используется одна маска и потом анимируют слои трансформами.

Ниже пример, особо сильно не заморачивался но суть уловите.
Имеем одно изображение, два слоя с цветом, и маску, создаем ключевые кадры анимации и далее по очереди анимируем слои. Именно так сделано в примере который вы скинули.

```
.black {
   animation: black 2s linear forwards;
}
```

О всех параметрах можно почитать в спецификации css.

[https://jsfiddle.net/zovhqyxe/](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltrf5g4n/1/)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bg1 {
  background: url('https://i.ibb.co/G3qYhT1/2.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg2 {
  background: url('https://svgshare.com/i/i_L.svg') no-repeat center;
  animation: scale 2s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.white {
  background: white;
  animation: white 2s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
 
.black {
  background: #0c0c0c;
  animation: black 2s linear forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}



@keyframes black {
    0% {
       transform:translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
       transform:translateY(-100%);
    }
}
@keyframes white {
    0% {
       transform:translateY(0px);
    }
    100% {
       transform:translateY(-100%);
    }
}
@keyframes scale {
    0% {
      transform:scale(0px);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      transform:scale(2);
      opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class='wrap bg1'>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap white"></div>
    <div class="wrap black"></div>
    <div class="wrap bg2"></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### SVG mask animation

Используется свойство svg маски при `fill="black"` прорезать верхний слой и показывать нижний слой, на котором расположена картинка.

*Для начала анимации кликните по по цветным полоскам*

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600"  style="border:1px solid;">  
     <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
     </linearGradient>
        <!-- Маска -->
     <mask id="msk1" > 
           <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="white" /> 
          <!-- Анимация левой половины маски   -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="300" height="600" fill="black" >
           <!-- Анимация правой половины маски   -->         
         <animate attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="0;-300;-300;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
       </rect> 
         <rect x="300" y="0" width="300" height="600" fill="black" >
          <animate attributeName="x" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="300;600;600;300;300" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
       </rect>
     </mask>
     </defs>
      <rect  width="600" height="600"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
          <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhtOM.jpg" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" /> 

</svg>
```

Ещё пример, основанный на этом же принципе работы маски

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600" >  
     <defs>
         <!-- Многоцветный радиальный градиент -->
     <radialGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">

        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="10%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
       <stop offset="20%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="30%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#503969" />  
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
       <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
        <stop offset="70%" stop-color="#b4c63b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#ef5b2b" />
        <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#503969" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#ab6294" />
        <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#1cb98f" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#48afc1" />
     </radialGradient>
         <!-- Маска -->
     <mask id="msk1" > 
            <rect  width="100%" height="100%"  fill="black" /> 
             
       <circle cx="300" cy="300"  r="0" fill="white" >
            <!-- Анимация маски прорезающей изображение дракончика и показывающее радиальный градиент  -->
         <animate attributeName="r" begin="svg1.click" dur="8s" values="0;300;300;0;0" fill="freeze" repeatCount="3" />
        </circle>
     </mask>
     </defs> 
               <!-- Фоновое изображение радиальный градиент   -->
      <circle  cx="300" cy="300"  r="300"  fill="url(#grad)"  />  
                 
          <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kywq.png" x="-140" y="-60" mask="url(#msk1)" width="800" height="780" />  

</svg>
```